# How to get cropped image and display it in an ImageView?

Tags: android

I am using Android Image Cropper [Android Image Cropper](https://github.com/ArthurHub/Android-Image-Cropper).
I have the following code already, to pick image from either gallery or camera, https://github.com/ArthurHub/Android-Image-Cropper/wiki/Pick-image-for-cropping-from-Camera-or-Gallery.

This is my current code:

MainActivity.java:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private Button changeImageButton;
    private Uri mCropImageUri;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        changeImageButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.changeImage);
        changeImageButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                onSelectImageClick(v);
            }
        });


    }
    @Override
    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        // handle result of pick image chooser
        if (requestCode == CropImage.PICK_IMAGE_CHOOSER_REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            Uri imageUri = CropImage.getPickImageResultUri(this, data);

            // For API >= 23 we need to check specifically that we have permissions to read external storage.
            if (CropImage.isReadExternalStoragePermissionsRequired(this, imageUri)) {
                // request permissions and handle the result in onRequestPermissionsResult()
                mCropImageUri = imageUri;

                requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},   CropImage.PICK_IMAGE_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CODE);
            } else {
                // no permissions required or already granted, can start crop image activity
                startCropImageActivity(imageUri);
            }
        }
    }

    public void onSelectImageClick(View view) {
        CropImage.startPickImageActivity(this);
    }

    private void startCropImageActivity(Uri imageUri) {
        CropImage.activity(imageUri).setCropShape(CropImageView.CropShape.RECTANGLE).setFixAspectRatio(true)
                .start(this);

    }

}
```

This is the activity_main xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/changeImage"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
        android:text="Change Image"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.501"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />



</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

It's working great, when I click the button, I get a dialog that asks me from where I want to take an image: gallery, camera, files, etc. And when I choose either, I get to the cropping activity. But after I click crop, nothing happens. How do I get the cropped image in my existing code, and set it to a square image view, let's say 150x150dp size. I don't know what callback I should use to save the cropped / rotated image? Because this cropper seem to mix few API's versions together so I'm confused as to how I need to do that. Help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

```
private ImageView open_gallary;
```

inside your `OnCreate()`

```
open_gallary.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                int permissionCheck = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(), android.Manifest.permission.CAMERA);
                if (permissionCheck != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    permission();
                }else {
                    CropImage.activity()
                    .start(getContext(), Register.this);

                }


            }
        });
```

And your permission method is :

```
   public void permission() {
        final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(getActivity(), android.R.style.Theme_Translucent_NoTitleBar);
        dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_permission);
        dialog.show();
        Button cancel_log, open;
        ImageView close_dialog;
        open = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.open);
        open.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                dialog.cancel();
                final Intent i = new Intent();
                i.setAction(Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS);
                i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);
                i.setData(Uri.parse("package:" + getActivity().getPackageName()));
                i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);
                i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_EXCLUDE_FROM_RECENTS);
                getActivity().startActivity(i);

            }
        });

        cancel_log = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.cancel_log);
        cancel_log.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                dialog.cancel();
            }
        });
        close_dialog = (ImageView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.close_dialog);
        close_dialog.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                dialog.cancel();
            }
        })
}
```

and to set your image use this :

```
 Uri uri;

public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == CropImage.CROP_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE) {
        CropImage.ActivityResult result = CropImage.getActivityResult(data);
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            uri = result.getUri();
            open_gallary.setImageURI(uri);////set the image after taking it
        } else if (resultCode == CropImage.CROP_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_RESULT_ERROR_CODE) {
            Exception error = result.getError();
        }
    }
}
```

And dont forget

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
```